# Get gmail message IDs using a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that will take each selected email in the inbox and process it. The actual processing bit is already built and is currently sat in a contextual gadget, so can be re-used.

Here's where I've got to so far.

```
{
  "name": "Test execution",
  "description": "Does this trigger myscript.js",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Does it execute?"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "myscript.js"},function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });

});
```

myscript.js:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("zA yO x7");
alert(x.length);

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    alert(x[i].innerHTML);
}
```

This is correctly selecting just the ticked messages, but I can't see how to get from there to get the actual messages - only the preview information that visible in the inbox. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose I could get the sender, subject, time received and search using Google APIs but that seems a little clunky.

Comment: Not a full answer, but [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js) is a good match here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but I'm working on something similar and I wanted to share my solution. Please, note that this is not an elegant or clean solution, but it works, at least until Google decides to change their Gmail user interface.

The key of my solution is to use the VIEW_DATA variable, which contains a lot of information about the emails, including their IDs.

First of all, we have to get the indexes of the selected emails:

```
    var selectedIndexes = [];
    var checkBoxes = $jQcl('[role="checkbox"]');
    //Looks for selected mails
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].attributes.class &&
            checkBoxes[i].attributes.class.value.indexOf("oZ-jc") > -1  &&
            checkBoxes[i].attributes['aria-checked'] &&
            checkBoxes[i].attributes['aria-checked'].value == "true")
            {
                //Saves the index of the selected mail
                selectedIndexes.push(i);
            }
    }

    // Iterates through the indexes of the selected mails and gets their IDs
    var selectedIds = [];
    selectedIndexes.forEach( function(elem) {
        selectedIds.push(getMailID(elem));
    });

    return selectedIds;
```

And the `getMailID` function:

```
        //Returns the ID of the email looking for its index.
        //
        //<param name="indexSelected">Index of the selected email</param>
        var getMailID = function (indexSelected)
        {
            // Puts the index in (0-9) array format
            indexSelected--;

            // gets all of the <script> elements on the page
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' ),
                thisScript, varViewDataPos, viewDataScript, viewData;

            // loop through each one looking for VIEW_DATA being defined
            for( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++ ) {
                thisScript = scripts[ i ].textContent;
                varViewDataPos = thisScript.indexOf( 'var VIEW_DATA=' );

                if( varViewDataPos >= 0 ) {
                    // might as well toss everything before VIEW_DATA is defined
                    viewDataScript = thisScript.slice( varViewDataPos );
                    break;
                }
            }

            // eval what we found (if anything), but in a closure to avoid polluting
            // the global namespace
            viewData = ( function( script ) {
                eval( script );
                return VIEW_DATA;
            } )( viewDataScript );

            //Goes through the VIEW_DATA looking for the mails info
            //I know this is ugly, but it works
            preDataMail = viewData[Math.floor(indexSelected/10)+3];
            preDataMail = preDataMail[2];
            preDataMail = preDataMail[indexSelected % 10];
            preDataMail = preDataMail[2];

            //Returns the mail ID
            return preDataMail;
        }
```